# Authentication/Authorization for default resolvers

Tags: django, graphql, graphene-python

I read the description on how to use [@login_required](https://github.com/flavors/django-graphql-jwt/wiki/Auth-decorators#login_required) and other decorators with resolvers. However, if one is not using explicit resolvers (instead using default ones), how can one enforce similar access controls?

In my case, I am using graphene with the Django User model. I have the following:

```
class UserNode(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        filter_fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'id', 'email']
        interfaces = (Node, )

class Query(object):
    userNode = relay.Node.Field(UserNode)
    all_users = DjangoConnectionField(UserNode)
```

If I explicitly define a 'resolve_all_users' method and use the @login_required decorator on it, it works fine. But this (and other objects) in my schema are relying on default resolvers. How can I protect them without having to define resolvers explicitly?

I admit to being a novice in the use of graphene/graphql......and any help pointing me in the right direction is much appreciated.

Source: https://github.com/flavors/django-graphql-jwt/issues/36

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way of doing it not explicitly defining `resolve_` method.

But you still can inherit `Field` class and add extra constructor argument to support this feature or use `resolve_` :)

Comment: Best place to do it is in `get_queryset` method. But that only works if you're using `DjangoObjectType`